# Desalinhamento de linha

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Utilizando o `bootstrap` tenho o seguinte código [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/2o07iH7qyC):

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Seja bem vindo <small>Selecione um curso:</small></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="well col-sm-4">
            <h4 class="text-center"><strong>Aminésia de velhos e novos durante a vida toda Aminésia de velhos e novos durante a vida toda</strong> </h4>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Turma:</strong> Turma 4</h5>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Inicio:</strong> 01/01/2014</h5>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Final:</strong> 01/12/2014</h5>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success center-block">Acessar</a>
        </div>

        <div class="well col-sm-4">
            <h3 class="text-center"><strong>Curso:</strong> Aminésia</h3>
            <h4 class="text-center"><strong>Turma:</strong> Turma 4</h4>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Inicio:</strong> 01/01/2014</h5>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Final:</strong> 01/12/2014</h5>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success center-block">Acessar</a>
        </div>

        <div class="well col-sm-4">
            <h3 class="text-center"><strong>Curso:</strong> Aminésia</h3>
            <h4 class="text-center"><strong>Turma:</strong> Turma 4</h4>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Inicio:</strong> 01/01/2014</h5>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Final:</strong> 01/12/2014</h5>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success center-block">Acessar</a>
        </div>
        <div class="well col-sm-4">
            <h3 class="text-center"><strong>Curso:</strong> Aminésia</h3>
            <h4 class="text-center"><strong>Turma:</strong> Turma 4</h4>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Inicio:</strong> 01/01/2014</h5>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Final:</strong> 01/12/2014</h5>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success center-block">Acessar</a>
        </div>

        <div class="well col-sm-4">
            <h3 class="text-center"><strong>Curso:</strong> Aminésia</h3>
            <h4 class="text-center"><strong>Turma:</strong> Turma 4</h4>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Inicio:</strong> 01/01/2014</h5>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Final:</strong> 01/12/2014</h5>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success center-block">Acessar</a>
        </div>

        <div class="well col-sm-4">
            <h3 class="text-center"><strong>Curso:</strong> Aminésia</h3>
            <h4 class="text-center"><strong>Turma:</strong> Turma 4</h4>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Inicio:</strong> 01/01/2014</h5>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Final:</strong> 01/12/2014</h5>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success center-block">Acessar</a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

O problema está na primeira `div`, ela possui um texto maior que as outras portanto a `div` abaixo perde o alinhamento da linha.

Essas `divs` são geradas dinamicamente. Sei que posso estar fazendo um `if` para estar adicionando uma `row` a cada 3 `divs`.

Mas gostaria de saber se tem uma outra forma sem poluir com `ifs`.

Comment: Você não pode definir uma altura mínima pro box que comporte o maior texto que existir?

Comment: @bfavaretto, não entendi!

Comment: Esse problema é por causa da maneira como os floats funcionam (os `<div class="well">` são flutuados). Se todos os divs tiverem a mesma altura, o problema some. Estou sugerindo que você engesse a altura dos divs para um tamanho razoável para caber o maior texto. Exemplo: http://www.bootply.com/vuZL97HOLB

Comment: @bfavaretto, entendi... Isso é melhor do que adicionar uma row?

Comment: Não tenho muita experiência com o bootstrap, adicionar uma row parece outra boa solução.

Comment: Cara isso pode resolver o seu problema,
tive o mesmo recentemente e foi o que eu precisava. http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O teu problema é o fato de que cada elemento com a classe `col-sm-4` ou qualquer outro `col-X` é flutuado à esquerda pois é a forma sob a qual a framework trabalha as colunas.

No que respeita ao HTML a solução é envolver cada 12 colunas numa linha tal como ditado pela  framework que estás a utilizar:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">5</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">6</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

## Solução

Podes aplicar uma solução de duas formas, tudo dependendo da maneira como colocas os elementos na página:

#### Via PHP

Se o PHP é quem gera o teu HTML para apresentar na página, uma simples verificação é suficiente para organizar as colunas em grupos de 12 dentro de linhas.

Exemplo

```php
$dados = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8");

echo '<div class="container"><div class="row">';

$i=1;

foreach($dados as $col) {

    echo '<div class="col-sm-4">'.$col.'</div>';

    if ($i%3==0) {
        echo '</div><div class="row">';
    }

    $i++;
}

echo '</div></div>';
```

Resultado:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">5</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">7</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ver exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/VoUkNU).

### Via jQuery

Se a organização dos elementos tiver que ser realizada no lado do cliente, ou seja, através da manipulação do DOM, podes fazer uso de jQuery para pegar em blocos de 3 `<div/>` e envolver as mesmas numa `<div class="row"/>`.

Exemplo:

```js
var divs = $(".container > div");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 3) {
    divs.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<div class='row'></div>");
}
```

O resultado é igual ao em cima apresentado para PHP, mas montei um exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLoqhhcv/) onde usei a classe `col-xs-4` para que as colunas sejam sempre visíveis mesmo em dispositivos com ecrã super-pequeno.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divs = $(".container > div");
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 3) {
    divs.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<div class='row'></div>");
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well col-xs-4">texto</div>
  <div class="well col-xs-4">mais texto que o texto</div>
  <div class="well col-xs-4">3</div>
  <div class="well col-xs-4">texto</div>
  <div class="well col-xs-4">bué da mais texto que o texto do texto</div>
  <div class="well col-xs-4">6</div>
  <div class="well col-xs-4">7</div>
  <div class="well col-xs-4">8</div>
</div>
```

---

**Nota:** Apresentei as soluções *server-side* e *client-side* para a linguagem e framework mais comum, mas a lógica é a mesma para qualquer outra tipo ASP ou JavaScript nativo.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de resolver esse problema:

Utilizando "row" para cada conjunto de colunas (até fechar o grid de 12):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: O problema é que o conteúdo é adicionado dinamicamente, então precisaria fazer um if para estar vendo quando tem 3, para estar adicionando e fechando uma row.